# How to fill adobe reader protected forms in pdf?

Tags: php, pdf-editor, pdf-generation

There are some immigration pdf forms that are protected to open just on adobe reader and have some other restriction like importing data inside adobe. I saw some softwares that found a way to automatic fill-in this forms. Does anyone know a library or API that can help me to do that.
My software is made with php/laravel.

This is one of the company doing it: https://support.caseeasy.ca/en/articles/5986426-add-forms-to-a-case-record-send-the-auto-complete-request

This is one of forms: https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/kits/forms/imm1294e.pdf Thank you!

Tried some php library to fill forms, but they can't even open the file.